# Importing numpy statement in script

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I am a matlab coder and have dabbled in and out of Python for various things.  One very basic concept/thing in python which I have not got to the bottom of relates to the from and import statements.

When i import bitarray from the bitarray module (am I correct saying this?) using example 1) I just call it's methods when I want to use them in the script that follows.  However, when i import numpy I cannot use the code shown in 2) as it throws an error, i have to use the statement in 3) then type np. before using any of its methods, which makes sense.  I can also import bitarray using similer syntax which i have shown in 4) below.......  why does 2) not work when 1) does? I am praying for a simple explanation :) .....

1)

```
from bitarray import bitarray
```

2)

```
from numpy import numpy
```

3)

```
import numpy as np
```

4)

```
import bitarray as pp
```

Comment: I have no idea *why*, but another alternative is "from numpy import *"

Comment: Reading the docs might help: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @mauve please don't encourage bad practice. don't use `from import *` especially for numpy since it contains functions that will override builtins.

Comment: @M4tini thanks! I did not know it was bad practice. I don't remember where I saw it, but I have definitely done it occasionally.

Comment: @mauve I have mentioned this at the bottom of my answer - note the examples demonstrating why this is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the different package structures between `bitarray` and `numpy`; specifically, one contains an object with the same name as the module itself, the other doesn't.

The `bitarray` module contains a class called `bitarray`, (similarly, for the example, the `datetime` module in the standard library contains the `datetime` class) . Hence the following are equivalent:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
ba = bitarray(...)
```

and

```
import bitarray
ba = bitarray.bitarray(...)
```

In the former we `import` the *class* `bitarray` directly into the current namespace from the module; in the latter we import the *whole module* as `bitarray` and need to access the class by specifying the module namespace.

By contrast, `numpy` does not contain an object named `numpy`, so

```
from numpy import numpy
```

doesn't work.

---

The `as` is separate; that simply allows you to provide an alias for whatever you're importing, so any of the following will work fine:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(...)

from bitarray import bitarray as pp
b = pp(...)

import bitarray as pp
b = pp.bitarray(...)
```

---

As `mauve` comments above, you can use the `*` "wildcard import" to import everything, so:

```
from numpy import *
from bitarray import *
```

will import every top-level name in both modules into the current namespace. Afterwards, e.g.

```
a = array(...)
b = bitarray(...)
```

will both work fine. However, this is [not recommended](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) as it is generally a bad idea - for example, [`numpy` contains a definition of `all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562849/how-to-use-a-built-in-function-if-its-name-is-used-by-another-module) which will shadow the built-in function of the same name if you import everything.

Also, it makes it much more difficult for anyone reading your code (including a later version of you!) to figure out where the classes and functions being used have come from. Compare:

```
from numpy import *
from random import *

a = choice([1, 2, 3]) # which module did choice come from?
b = all(x == y for x in l) # is this numpy's all or the built-in?
```

with the much clearer:

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = random.choice([1, 2, 3]) # clearly from random
b = all(x == y for x in l) # must be the built-in, not np.all()
```

Comment: Great, that has saved me from reaching for the paracetamol again!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) If `bitarray` is a *function* or *class* name in the *library* `bitarray` then it is perfectly valid.

2) This doesn't make sense because `numpy` doesn't have a function named `numpy`.

3) This is fine because you are importing a library and assigning it an alias.

4) This is fine as well because again you are simply importing under an alias.

Comment: for completeness: `bitarray` does not have to be `function` or `class`. It could as well just be an ordinary variable. `import` simply imports "names", irrespective of what type of object this name is bound to.